# Importing a sql file using a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, xampp

I'm trying to make a batch file which creates a database in PHPmyAdmin then imports a database file. This is what I'm using below.

```
@echo on
C:\xampp\xampp_start
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -e "DROP DATABASE selkirk_stock_control";
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS selkirk_stock_control";
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p selkirk_stock_control ^< C:\xampp\htdocs\30316755\capstone-projects-2020-selkirk-stock-control\Inventory\config\dummyData.sql
pause
```

Can anyone see why it's not working?

Comment: Why are you escaping the input redirection character, **`<`**, with a caret **`^`**? What happens if you don't? You have posted seven commands within your question, which one(s) are/aren't working as expected? Can you provide debugging information to assist us?

Comment: Sorry about that. it's just the last one that isn't working C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p selkirk_stock_control ^< C:\xampp\htdocs\30316755\capstone-projects-2020-selkirk-stock-control\Inventory\config\dummyData.sql

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with how this works :(

Comment: This is the error C:\xampp\htdocs\30316755\capstone-projects-2020-selkirk-stock-control\Scripts>C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p selkirk_stock_control  0<C:\xampp\htdocs\30316755\capstone-projects-2020-selkirk-stock-control\Inventory\config\dummyData.sql
The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I got rid of the ^ and changed the file path. It was incorrect.

```
@echo on
C:\xampp\xampp_start
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -e "DROP DATABASE selkirk_stock_control";
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS selkirk_stock_control";
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p selkirk_stock_control < C:\xampp\htdocs\30316755\capstone-projects-2020-selkirk-stock-control\Inventory\config\sql\selkirk_stock_control.sql
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p selkirk_stock_control < C:\xampp\htdocs\30316755\capstone-projects-2020-selkirk-stock-control\Inventory\config\dummyData\dummyData.sql
pause
```

Comment: Do you mean, "Thank you @Compo for identifying the issue nineteen and a half hours ago."?